# How do I know when a function with a setimeout and foreach inside its finished

Tags: jquery

```
var radar = function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('span.dot').each(function (i, elem) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var randNumLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 301) + 70;
                var randNumTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 301) + 67;
                $(elem)
                    .css('left', randNumLeft + 'px')
                    .css('top', randNumTop + 'px')
                    .show();
            }, i * 200);
        })
    }, 3000);
}
```

I have the previous function and I want to know when this is done. I used done() and promise() at the end but it executes whatever I have after 3 seconds.

Comment: You could pass the function that you want to execute as a callback parameter and call it from within the timeout/loop whenever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a promise like

```
var radar = function () {
    //create a promise
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () {
        var $spans = $('span.dot'),
            len = $spans.length;
        $spans.each(function (i, elem) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var randNumLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 301) + 70;
                var randNumTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 301) + 67;
                $(elem)
                    .css('left', randNumLeft + 'px')
                    .css('top', randNumTop + 'px')
                    .show();
                //since the items are processed sequencely if this is the last item then all other items are processed
                if (i == len - 1) {
                    deferred.resolve();
                }
            }, i * 200);
        });
    }, 3000);
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

then

```
radar().done(function () {
    //all done
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vj0sjczy/)

Comment: I will read more into the Deferred function. Thank You, It was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
setTimeout(function () {

 successfunc('1');

 },3000);

function successfunc(get){

if(get == 1){
    console.log('success');
}else{
  console.log('failure');
}

}
```

Comment: the problem is that this will execute after the 3 seconds, and I need to know when the loop is done as well

Comment: both are same @Monica

Comment: just tried it and it executes after the 3 seconds, not after the 3 secs and the loop finished